# Non-aggregate update of `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Consider a dataframe grouped by a column.

```
example = pandas.DataFrame({
    'A': numpy.arange(100) // 10,
    'B': numpy.nan
})
```

Now I wish to update a column by doing some calculations on each of the groups. The result is a series, and not a single aggregate number like the mean or median. One solution is this:

```
for a, rows in example.groupby('A'):
    # Some update that is performed per group
    some_update = numpy.arange(len(rows))
    # slow:
    example.loc[rows.index, 'B'] = some_update
```

However, I notice the `example.loc[...] = ...` statement takes up most time, which is a shame especially when the groups are continuous partitions in the original DataFrame.

Is it possible to `groupby` and have rows be a subset view on the original data, such that updates are passed through to the original DataFrame?

Comment: Does this work for you : ``pd.concat( [value.assign(B=np.arange(len(value))) for key, value in example.groupby("A")])``?

Comment: `example.groupby("A")["B"].cumcount()`?

Comment: @HenryYik Thanks! So the `numpy.arange(...)` was just an example, to avoid my question from getting complicated. It could be anything that updates the group. In my case it's a time series from different experiments in which days separated by zero-signals were enumerated using a heuristic.

Comment: @sammywemmy Wouldn't the `pandas.concat` be slow?

Comment: @Herbert the `slowness` will come from the for loop, not necessarily from the concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try it with `transform`, as another option to my earlier suggestion:

```
example.assign(B=example.groupby("A").transform(lambda x: range(len(x))))
```

Comment: This seems very elegant, let me check if it speeds up things, is `example.assign` fast?

Comment: speed is relative. You have to compare it to something. I'd like to believe that it is faster than the pandas concat solution I proffered earlier. assign creates a new dataframe. keen to know what the speed outcome is